# Plugin API for easy admin list table generation, handling & exporting of MySQL tables?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, export, wp-list-table

I'm aware of the `WP_List_Table` class (which has helped tremendously as it stands).

However, I'm hunting for something even more capable - some form of API whereby you could simply 'register' a MySQL table, pass `field_name => label` translations, and all the hard graft (menu links, table-generation, pagination, column sorting) & possibly data exporting (CSV etc.) is done for you automagically!

I know this is an *extremely* specific request, but I thought it was worth asking. If anyone knows of anything *remotely* similar, please speak up! Heck, if there's nothing out there at the moment, I might just build it myself if this raises interest...

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting project. Probably best if in some way connected to WP_List_Table, either as a sub class or a copy. One other thing to consider is a related mysql meta table.

Comment: I don't know of anything like this, and it sure sounds like a fascinating project. If you decide to start something open source and want any help, I'd love to contribute!

Comment: Upvoted to raise your rep points from 4,999 > 5k+ - Good Q also.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/scribu/wp-scb-framework/wiki

This guy has built what you are looking for I believe. He's a core-contributor and his code is top notch. And the project is open on github, so even better right?

Comment: Thanks for the link - I'd actually checked out this library before, impressive bit of a kit, but not quite what I'm after (it's a great API for, among many things, database table & admin page creation, but not the whole kit and kaboodle ;)